# Count number of records with identical values in selected columns within an interval

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to identify if there are more than 5 emails sent with same subject and email within 15 minutes.

I currently have query as such:

```
SELECT
    frommail,
    SUBJECT,
    message,
    count(*) AS count
FROM
    compose
GROUP BY
    frommail,
    SUBJECT,
    message;
```

But this returns count of all identical records of that table, but I need to have a condition if the count is greater than 5 in a any 15 minute interval.

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `compose` (
  `id` int(50) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cc` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bcc` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `subject` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `message` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `files` blob,
  `frommail` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `attached` varchar(30) DEFAULT 'no',
  `vstatus` varchar(30) DEFAULT 'new',
  `rstatus` varchar(30) DEFAULT 'no',
  `mstatus` varchar(39) DEFAULT 'inbox',
  `port` int(10) NOT null,
  `date` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Sample Data:

```
id email cc bc subject message files frommail attached vstatus rstatus mstatus port date
24  abc         Normal mail Hello       rohan   no  new no  inbox   8080    2016-02-22 19:58:20
25  abc         Normal mail Hello       rohan   no  new no  inbox   8080    2016-02-22 19:58:20
26  abc         Normal mail Hello       rohan   no  new no  inbox   8080    2016-02-22 20:23:13
27  abc         Normal mail Hello       rohan   no  new no  inbox   8080    2016-02-22 20:23:13
28  abc         Normal mail Hello       rohan   no  new no  inbox   8080    2016-02-22 20:23:13
29  abc         Normal mail Hello       rohan   no  new no  inbox   8080    2016-02-22 20:23:13
30  abc         Normal mail Hello       rohan   no  new no  inbox   8080    2016-02-22 20:23:13
31  abc         Normal mail Hello       rohan   no  new no  inbox   7070    2016-02-22 20:34:21
32  abc         Normal mail Hello       rohan   no  new no  inbox   7075    2016-02-22 20:34:21
33  abc         Normal mail Hello       rohan   no  new no  inbox   7080    2016-02-22 20:34:21
34  abc         Normal mail Hello       rohan   no  new no  inbox   8080    2016-02-22 20:34:21
35  abc         Normal mail Hello       rohan   no  new no  inbox   7070    2016-02-22 20:34:21
```

I do have insertion timestamp as date.

Any advice will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: can you share table structure and some sample data?

Comment: Basically, what I am trying to find is if email sent 5 times or more within any 15 minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this mate:

```
Select count(e1.id), 
frommail,  
SUBJECT,
    message
from email e1
left join email e2
on e1.date>date_add(e2.date,interval 15 minute)
having count(*)>5
```

Basicly it compares the table with itself and shows if it has records with more than 15 minutes with other records.

Comment: @rohan can you mark the answer pls, i want more points mate. Glad it worked.